# 301 redirect everything to new root?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am trying to do a 301 redirect of everything from an old subdomain to a new.

I have a simple .htaccess

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.smartphonesoft.com/
```

However if I goto the old URL with a subdir, it tries to redirect to the new domain with a subdir and fails.

ie

http://forum.smartphonesoft.com/reminder/

goes to

http://www.smartphonesoft.com/reminder/

When I would like it to goto

http://www.smartphonesoft.com/

How can I have everything simply redirected to the new domain root?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) you define the base path (path prefix) that is to be redirected; every path beyond that is redirected while just replacing the base path with the new base path.

If you want to stick with [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html), you can use [`RedirectMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) and omit the match:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/ http://www.smartphonesoft.com/
```

Comment: +1 for posting the answer I should have thought of originally, while I was editing, heh.

Comment: thanks, that seems to work for everything, except.... http://forum.smartphonesoft.com/reminder/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your server has support for `mod_rewrite`, you can do this:

```
RewriteRule . http://www.smartphonesoft.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Alternatively, sticking to `mod_alias`, this should also work (but I haven't tried it):

```
RedirectMatch 301 .* http://www.smartphonesoft.com/
```